# How to add external HTML page to my current page which is another HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I am working on a project where I have to add external HTML files as a header and footer in the main (Index.html) page. I tried below script, but it didn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>sample test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  

  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#header1').load("mainheader.html");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can solve the problem with the `iframe` tag, but then your page will not be indexed by browsers. The `load()` method handles this well. You may have given the wrong path. What is displayed in the "Network" tab of your browser?

Comment: Hi @sergeykuznetsov, the page is in the same folder and the path is correct. As you said Iframe is not recommended, please help me if there is any possible scenario.

Comment: is your project local? and what does the browser console ("Network" tab) write?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe tag to load another html file or url.

```
<iframe src="your-html-route/another.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript and work with components. Then you can work with modules to import or export a component and add HTML with

```
document.queryselector('#header').innerHTML = '<header>content</header>';
```

PHP is better for such a thing if you ask me. Make you header and footer in another .php file and include them on every page where you want use them.

Comment: Hi @Thibaut, I am trying to load external html page. It is not  a small code.

Comment: I would recommend that you use PHP or a static site generator. But PHP is more usefull into my eyes.

Comment: Hi @Thibaut, We are only allowed to use HTML,CSS,JS in our project php is not recommended for our project.Please help me with supporting scenario.

Comment: You can use the piece of code I added here above. I recommend you to learn the javascript DOM on w3schools. Than you only have to put your html code for that component in the string and it will load inside the html.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your script `$('#header1').load("mainheader.html");` is correct. The fact is that the `load()` method (just like `ajax`) works exclusively on the SERVER. In order to load an external page to your tag using the `load()` method, you need to put your project on the server, or deploy a local server on your computer. There are many programs for this, for example: OpenServer, Denwer, WampServer, XAMPP, etc. I advise you to use OpenServer. It's free and easy to use. After you deploy your local server, you push your project to your server and the `load()` method will load your external html file.

Answer (score -1):

If it's only a short bit of code then you could use this:

```
 <pre>
  <code>
    HTML code goes
    here.
  </code>
 </pre>
```